# Android Proguard rules for TUNE sdk

Tags: android-proguard

What are the proguard rules for TUNE tracking SDK? Their website mentions you should add 2 lines but they are missing: `https://developers.tune.com/sdk/android-quick-start/#proguard`

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep public class com.tune.** { public *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.gcm.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent(**);
}
```